# Delete all the objects in the AWS-S3 bucket that have key with specific pattern?

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk

I want to delete all the objects from an s3 bucket that has the key with the certain pattern. My questions??

1. Can I  simply pass regular expression on the key value as illustrated in the code below?
2. One option would be to list all the objects and filter the keys that matches the regular expression and add them all to the deleteObjects method. I find this inefficient. So, any other way around?
   Would be a great help? Thanks in advance...

```js
var params = {
  Bucket: 'sample_bucket', 
  Delete: { 
    Objects: [ 
      {
        Key: '/video-044567/g' // here i want something like that
      },
      
    ],
  },
};

s3.deleteObjects(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
  else     console.log(data);           
});
```

Comment: Please accept my correct answer, even if you don't like that the answer is "no you can't"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `aws-sdk` NPM module, AWS.S3 class does not support recursive delete of objects.

If you really don't want to perform multiple operations to delete each object, consider using AWS CLI which supports `--recursive` delete based on folder prefix. Theoretically you could execute aws cli within Node JS depending on how your system credentials are configured.

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/rm.html

Comment: Well, thanks but i have more than 20 files for a  specific video  and i want to delete those files when user request to delete the video. So, can’t use CLI.

Comment: @SandeshPoudel In that case, you will have to list the files and then request the specific files to be deleted. You might consider it _inefficient_, but there is no wildcard delete capability in Amazon S3.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using aws cli : https://aws.amazon.com/cli/ and some unix command.

**this aws cli commands should work:**

```
aws s3 rm selina-data-lake-test --exclude "*" --include "<your_regex>"
```

if you want to include sub-folders you should add the flag **--recursive**

**or with unix commands:**

```
aws s3 ls s3://<your_bucket_name>/ | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I%  <your_os_shell>   -c 'aws s3 rm s3:// <your_bucket_name>  /% $1'
```

explanation:
list all files on the bucket **--pipe-->** 
get the 4th parameter(its the file name) **--pipe-->**
run delete script with aws cli